# Jquery doesnt get value

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to get the value of input but it dont wanna get it.

my code now is.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var value = .find('input');
    $("a#test").html(value);
});
```

```css
input{
    font-size: 25px;
    width: 37.5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #eff4f1;
    padding: 2px;
    text-align: center;
}
a.minus, a.plus{
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: orange;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputNumber">
    <a class="minus" id="minus">-</a>
    <input type="text" id="field" disabled="disabled" value="0">
    <a class="plus" id="plus">+</a>
    <a id="test"></a>
</div>
```

Hope you guys can help me.

Comment: You need to select the element and use `val()` to get the value: `var value = $('.inputNumber').find('input').val();`

Comment: Yeah it does: http://jsfiddle.net/ttcz715a/

Comment: oops didnt put $('.inputNumber') thx

Comment: Use your browser console to check for errors. Would certainly see one thrown from code above and would have given you an indication on where to start debugging